# How to join two tables just by using where and select operators

Tags: sql

What is the mysql command to join two columns where one table has the id and another table has the id and name by using where and select operators.

In table_a :

```
ID  |  NAME
1   |     A     
2   |     B     
3   |     C        
4   |     D
```

table_b :

```
ID  |    AGE    
1   |     60    
2   |     50    
3   |     40       
4   |     30
```

the expected result,

```
ID  |  NAME     |   AGE
1   |     A     |    60
2   |     B     |    50    
3   |     C     |    40       
4   |     D     |    30
```

Comment: By 'add' do you mean 'add to the output', concatenate, or add numbers together? And by 'using where and select' do you mean without using 'join', i.e. using the old-style join syntax? Either way there should be examples of [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) or old-style-joins ("from table1, table2") in the documentation.

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the question that you have asked is that you want to merge two tables and get the expected result.

For ex: let's take 2 tables called **table_a**  and  **table_b**

In table_a :

```
ID  |  NAME
1   |     A     
2   |     B     
3   |     C        
4   |     D
```

table_b :

```
ID  |    AGE    
1   |     60    
2   |     50    
3   |     40       
4   |     30
```

I would expect the result that you want is ,

```
ID  |  NAME     |   AGE
1   |     A     |    60
2   |     B     |    50    
3   |     C     |    40       
4   |     D     |    30
```

If so you can get the expected result by using the following sql command,

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,b.id,b.age
FROM `table_a ` a , `table_b ` b
WHERE  a.id= b.id ;
```

With   `FROM table_a  a , table_b  b` I'm assigning the 2 tables to a and b respectively so that it will make the query readable and more understandable.

**But Note  that its' always better to use `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.**

**Here are the different types of the JOINs in SQL:**

**(INNER) JOIN**: Returns records that have matching values in both tables.

**LEFT (OUTER) JOIN**: Returns all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table.

**RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN**: Returns all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table.

**FULL (OUTER) JOIN**: Returns all records when there is a match in either left or right table.

For further reference on joins you can use the following link. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Yeah that true.But what he wants to get the result just by using `select` and `where` operators.That's why I didn't use `JOIN` in the answer.

Comment: Many people asking questions here don't know what to ask for. Still give them a good answer, and they'll hopefully learn.